# UITableViewCell: Change checkbox border colour

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

May I know how can I change the checkbox border colour of UITableViewCell?

[image]

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: There is no such thing as Checkbox on UIKit. to change borders use element.layer.borderWidth

Comment: Use 2 separate images - selected and unselected for this instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding tint colour to the check mark image before assigning the image to the image view.

```
  let borderImage = self.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
      self.image = templateImage
      self.tintColor = newValue
```

You can also add it through storyboard by selecting the image view and adding tint color to it.